# Can a Gradle plugin modify the list of subprojects in a multi-module project?

Tags: gradle, multi-module

I've hacked together combination of `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` below for creating an ad-hoc multi-module project out of several single-module projects (e.g., an application and all of its dependencies, or a shared library and everything that uses that library).

`settings.gradle`:

```
// find all subprojects and include them
rootDir.eachFileRecurse { 
  if (it.name == "build.gradle") { 
    def projDir = it.parentFile
    if (projDir != rootDir) { 
      include projDir.name
      project(":${projDir.name}").projectDir = projDir
    }
  }
}
```

`build.gradle:`:

```
// Make sure we've parsed subproject dependencies
evaluationDependsOnChildren()

// Map of all projects by artifact group and name
def declarationToProject = subprojects.collectEntries { p -> [toDeclaration(p), p] }

// Replace artifact dependencies with subproject dependencies, if possible
subprojects.each { p ->
  def changes = [] // defer so we don't get ConcurrentModificationExceptions
  p.configurations.each { c ->
    c.dependencies.each { d ->
      def sub = declarationToProject[[group:d.group, name:d.name]]
      if (sub != null) {
        changes.add({
            c.dependencies.remove(d)
            p.dependencies.add(c.name, sub)
        })
      }
    }
  }
  for (change in changes) {
    change()
  }
}
```

This works, but it's hard to share -- if somebody else wants to do something similar they have to copy my `*.gradle` files or cut and paste.

What I'd like to do is take this functionality and encapsulate it in a plugin. The `build.gradle` part looks easy enough to do in the plugin `apply()` method, but it seems like the list of subprojects is already set in stone before the plugin gets a chance at it. Is there any way to get in earlier in the build process, e.g. by applying to something other than `Project`? Or should I resign myself to giving my plugin a task for overwriting `settings.gradle`?

---

**Solution:** Per [Peter Niederweiser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24820643/27358), I moved the code above into two plugins, one to be called from `settings.gradle` and the other to be called from `build.gradle`. In `settings.gradle:`

```
buildscript {
    repositories { /* etc... */ }
    dependencies { classpath 'my-group:my-plugin-project:1.0-SNAPSHOT' }
}

apply plugin: 'find-subprojects'
```

And in `build.gradle:`

```
buildscript {
    repositories { /* etc... */ }
    dependencies { classpath 'my-group:my-plugin-project:1.0-SNAPSHOT' }
}

evaluationDependsOnChildren()
apply plugin: 'local-dependencies'
```

Note that calling the plugin from `settings.gradle` doesn't work in Gradle 1.11 or 1.12 but does work in Gradle 2.0.

Comment: I'm close to 100% sure that you can only do this in your settings file, at least with the current Gradle 1.x/2.x versions. Of course, you could always fork Gradle and submit a pull request. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to apply a plugin in `settings.gradle`, which I believe is supported in recent versions.

Comment: Sounds promising. I've implemented a `Plugin<Settings>` but can't figure out how to get it loaded (`Plugin with id 'my-plugin' not found`). I thought it might be due to [GRADLE-2914](http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2914) but using the fully qualified class name instead of the ID I still get `Plugin with id 'mypackage.MyPluginClass' not found`. Is there a different mechanism I should be using to register plugins?

Comment: PS I have a `Plugin<Project>` in the same JAR and the `build.gradle` is finding that one just fine.

Comment: Do you have a `buildscript` block in `settings.gradle`, and have you tried with latest Gradle?

Comment: Didn't work in 1.12 but did work in 2.0, so that's excellent. Thank you!